# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference from server to spinner

Tags: java, mysql, xml, retrofit2, android-studio-3.0

i am try to fetch data from server to searchable spinner but show null .i am using
retrofit  and checking api on postman it show data but in android studio show null.i am showing only country name from mysql databse sorry for bad english
thanks advance to solve my problem.

```
public class LabourRegActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> countryname = new ArrayList<String>();
    SearchableSpinner countryS,catagoryS,cityS,projectbaseS,district;
    EditText name,contact,cnic,perdayrate,address;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_labour_reg);



        countryS = findViewById(R.id.country_spinner);
        catagoryS = findViewById(R.id.skill_spinner);
        cityS = findViewById(R.id.city_spinner);
        projectbaseS = findViewById(R.id.projectBase);
        district = findViewById(R.id.district_Spinner);

        name = findViewById(R.id.Edt_name);
        contact = findViewById(R.id.Edt_contact);
        cnic = findViewById(R.id.Edt_cnic);
        perdayrate = findViewById(R.id.Edt_perdays);
        address = findViewById(R.id.Edt_address);



        CountryFetchApi fetchApi = ApiClient.getClient().create(CountryFetchApi.class);
//        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        Log.d("ok","countryMap"+fetchApi);
        Call<List<CountryModel>> model = fetchApi.getcountryrecord();
        model.enqueue(new Callback<List<CountryModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<CountryModel>> call, Response<List<CountryModel>> response) {
                List<CountryModel> data = response.body();
                Log.d("ok","country"+response.body());
                for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                    countryname.add(data.get(i).getCountryName());
                }
                Log.d("leavename", countryS.toString());


                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(LabourRegActivity.this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,countryname);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                countryS.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<CountryModel>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you pls add the code for the `CountryModel` and the json response you're receiving? It can be that the mapping is not correct

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CountryModel {


    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("skill")
    @Expose
    private String skill;
    @SerializedName("cnic")
    @Expose
    private Object cnic;
    @SerializedName("contact_number")
    @Expose
    private String contactNumber;
    @SerializedName("labour_amount")
    @Expose
    private String labourAmount;
    @SerializedName("perday_project")
    @Expose
    private Integer perdayProject;
    @SerializedName("company_amount")
    @Expose
    private String companyAmount;
    @SerializedName("address")
    @Expose
    private String address;
    @SerializedName("category_name")
    @Expose
    private String categoryName;
    @SerializedName("city_name")
    @Expose
    private String cityName;
    @SerializedName("province")
    @Expose
    private String province;
    @SerializedName("country_name")
    @Expose
    private String countryName;
    @SerializedName("district_name")
    @Expose
    private String districtName;


    public CountryModel() {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.skill = skill;
        this.cnic = cnic;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
        this.labourAmount = labourAmount;
        this.perdayProject = perdayProject;
        this.companyAmount = companyAmount;
        this.address = address;
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.province = province;
        this.countryName = countryName;
        this.districtName = districtName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getCountryName();
    }


    public String getId() {
        return String.valueOf(id);
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSkill() {
        return skill;
    }

    public void setSkill(String skill) {
        this.skill = skill;
    }

    public Object getCnic() {
        return cnic;
    }

    public void setCnic(Object cnic) {
        this.cnic = cnic;
    }

    public String getContactNumber() {
        return contactNumber;
    }

    public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    }

    public String getLabourAmount() {
        return labourAmount;
    }

    public void setLabourAmount(String labourAmount) {
        this.labourAmount = labourAmount;
    }

    public Integer getPerdayProject() {
        return perdayProject;
    }

    public void setPerdayProject(Integer perdayProject) {
        this.perdayProject = perdayProject;
    }

    public String getCompanyAmount() {
        return companyAmount;
    }

    public void setCompanyAmount(String companyAmount) {
        this.companyAmount = companyAmount;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    public String getProvince() {
        return province;
    }

    public void setProvince(String province) {
        this.province = province;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public String getDistrictName() {
        return districtName;
    }

    public void setDistrictName(String districtName) {
        this.districtName = districtName;
    }

}
```